# PyTest MonkeyPatch.syspath_prepend persisting between test functions despite function scope

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm in a situation where I need to test code that uses a library that can't be imported outside of its proprietary runtime environment.

My solution to this: use monkeypatch's `syspath_prepend` function to patch in a stub library that mimics the proprietary library's API. This works in the forward direction - I can indeed mock the library, and import it where without a mock I normally could not.

**However**, this change persists beyond the function in which I perform the mock - if I mock the library in one test function, it stays mocked in all other functions. This is very bad.

Here's the code - the second test function does not raise a ModuleNotFound error, where I would expect it to.

**NOTE** - the second test will succeed if I only run it and not the first test. It only fails if I run the entire test module as a whole.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def useFakeLib(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.syspath_prepend("path/to/mockLib")


def test_can_import_fake_lib_via_conftest(useFakeLib):
    # Works!
    import proprietary_lib # imports API from mock library, not proprietary library
    assert proprietary_lib.fakeFunction() == "I am fake."



def test_proprietary_lib_is_not_normally_on_path():
    # Not using useFakeLib fixture, so mockLib should not be on path.
    # Fails
    with pytest.raises(ModuleNotFoundError):
        import proprietary_lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is not with the monkeypatch, which is removed after your first test, but rather with the fact that you have imported a module and this creates the `proprietary_lib` attribute for your entire test file (which is not removed automatically).

Try to do the following:

```
def test_can_import_fake_lib_via_conftest(useFakeLib):
    try:
        import proprietary_lib # imports API from mock library, not proprietary library
        assert proprietary_lib.fakeFunction() == "I am fake."
    finally:
        del proprietary_lib
```